# if文とDictionary.ContainsKey

Tags: c#, unity3d

## 前置き

Unity を用いてオリジナルゲームを制作しています。
プレイヤーの操作するキャラクターに足音を実装する作業を行っており、
現在は以下のサイトを参考に、キャラクターの足が接触したオブジェクトの tag を検知して再生するクリップを切り替えるプログラムを書いています。

[Unityで効果音とBGMを付ける (1) ～足音の基本と応用～](https://acua-piece.com/post/186042580240/game-audio-with-unity-footsteps)

---

## 本題

Dictionaryでtagの名前(string)と対応する番号(int)を決めて置き、if文を使って取得したtagの名前に一致するKeyがあるか調べてクリップを再生するメソッドをつくりました。

```
 public void RelayedTrigger(Collider other)
    {
        if(tagToIndex.ContainsKey(other.gameObject.tag))
        {
            groundIndex = tagToIndex[other.gameObject.tag];
        }
    }
```

`tagToIndex`にtagの名前と番号を対応させたDictionaryを代入しており、
`groundIndex`で最終的に再生するクリップを決定しています。

### 期待

実際に動作させたときには、if文中の内容が実行されてほしいのですが↓

### 結果

なぜか実行されません(elseで確認)。
なので、取得したtag名はtagToIndexのKeyに含まれていないということなのだと思いますが、
しかし↓

### 詳細

tagToIndexはちゃんと宣言・初期化できており(foreachで確認)、
Key名とtag名も一致しています。

### 補足

#### 追記1 : tagToIndex

`tagToIndex` ディクショナリに関連しているものを集めました。
`listAudioClips` にオブジェクトのtagと同名の要素を格納しています。

```
public class FootStepSEHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
   [System.Serializable]
    public class AudioClips
    {
        public string groundTypeTag;
    }

   [SerializeField] List<AudioClips> listAudioClips = new List<AudioClips>();

   private Dictionary<string, int> tagToIndex = new Dictionary<string, int>();

   private void Awake()
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < listAudioClips.Count(); ++i)
            tagToIndex.Add(listAudioClips[i].groundTypeTag, i);
   }
}
```

#### 追記2

どうやら足が地面に接触し、地面の`tag`を取得する前に足の親要素であるオブジェクトのコライダに判定をとられてしまい、その親のオブジェクトの`tag`を`tagToIndex`の`Key`と照らし合わせてしまっているようです。

#### 追記3

レイヤーと*LeyerCollisionMatrix*を用いてプレイヤーと足のコライダとの間で判定が
起こらないようにしました。
しかし、そもそも足のコライダが地面のコライダと接触していないようです。(`OnTriggerEnter()`が呼び出されていない)

Comment: よくある可能性としては片方に余分なスペースが入っていたり大文字/小文字や半角/全角が異なるケースが考えられます。`other.gameObject.tag.Trim()`に書き換えたりtagToIndexのキーにスペースが入っていないことを確認しても状況は変わらないでしょうか。

Comment: @payaneco Key と tag を確認し、念のためコピペしたので一致しているはずですが、変わりありませんでした。```other.gameObject.tag.Trim()```に変えましたが、やはり同様に変化ありませんでした。

Comment: tagToIndexの正確な型情報があると何かわかるかもしれません。

Comment: @sayuri 追記しました。お願いします。

Comment: 正しい動作をする foreach で RelayedTrigger() を実装したコードも比較のために載せてみてはいかがでしょうか。問題点が見つけやすくなると思います。

Comment: @nee 「```foreach```で```RelayedTrigger()```を実装」というのはどういうことでしょうか...?本文の詳細の項に書いたことであれば```Awake()```関数内で```foreach```の```Keys```プロパティを用いて調べた、ということなのですが...

Comment: RelayedTrigger() 内で ContainsKey() を使う代わりに foreach で Keys プロパティを判定することで実装できると思います。もしかしたら Awake() 時とは tagToIndex が異なっている可能性、比較方法に問題がある可能性が見えてくると思います。

Comment: @nee ```RelayedTrigger()```内のifの条件に使われている```ContainsKey()```を```foreach```に置き換えたところ、```CS1525 foreachは無効です。```というエラーが発生し、動作しません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 感謝

皆様の提案をもとに自己解決いたしました。ありがとうございます。

## 解決方法

コライダと`OnCollisionEnter()`、`OnTriggerEnter()`などの関数を使う際は、
衝突・侵入するコライダのアタッチされたオブジェクトのどちらか一方にリジッドボディ
コンポーネントがなければいけないようです。

判定を取得しているコライダのアタッチされたオブジェクト(プレイヤキャラクタの足)に
リジッドボディをアタッチすることですべて解決しました。

Answer (score 4):

本題に提示されているコードに不審な点は見つかりません。
単純に tagToIndex に other.gameObject.tag のキーが存在しないことを疑うべきでしょう。

Awake() で存在確認できていても、RelayedTrigger() 実行時にそのキーが存在するとは限りません。実行前に他のコードによって変更される可能性が否定できないためです。
なので、検証コードは RelayedTrigger() に実装して確認するのがよいと思います。

例えば、以下のようにします。

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;

public void RelayedTrigger(Collider other)
{
    if (tagToIndex.ContainsKey(other.gameObject.tag))
    {
        groundIndex = tagToIndex[other.gameObject.tag];
    }
    else
    {
        // 検証用コード：見つからないときに詳細にチェックする
        string tag = other.gameObject.tag;
        bool exists = false;
        Debug.Log("Check...");
        foreach (var key in tagToIndex.Keys)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Key: {GetStringWithHex(key)}");
            if (key == tag)
            {
                Debug.Log("** Find !! **");
                exists = true;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("Check done.");
        Debug.Log($"{GetStringWithHex(tag)} は" + (exists ? "見つかりました" : "見つかりませんでした"));
        Debug.Break(); // 実行を中断
    }
}

// 文字列に16新数表示を追加
private string GetStringWithHex(string input)
{
    return $"{input}({string.Join("-", input.ToCharArray().Select(e => Convert.ToInt32(e).ToString("X2")))})";
}
```

Comment: 回答の通りにしたところ、現在使用中の```key```がログに出力されました。しかし、その下のif文は実行されず、ログには```Playerは見つかりませんでした```と出力されました。

Comment: tagToIndex  に `Player` が含まれ、 other.gameobject.tag が `Player` なのに、 `key == tag` が偽になるということでしょうか。であれば、やはり実際には異なる文字列になっていると考えられます。前後のスペース、全角半角の違いなど、ご確認ください。

Comment: 文字列を16新数にして表示するようにしました。より詳細に違いが確認できると思います。

Comment: すみません、眠たい目をこすりながらのコメントでしたので言葉足らずが過ぎました。```tagToIndex```に```Player```は含まれません。別スクリプトでプレイヤの足にアタッチしたコライダが地面のコライダと接触したのを感知して```RelayedTrigger()```を呼び出すようにしているのですが、どうやらプレイヤ自体のコライダと接触し、処理が行われてしまっているようです。

Comment: それと、16進数を表示する文は```CS0103 現在のコンテキストに'Convert'という名前は存在しません```とエラーが出てしまいました。

Comment: エラーについては、コード例のように `using System;` を追加してください。